# tasks to be performed in a database maintenance plan in certain amount of time

Tags: sql-server, database, task, maintenance-plan

In a database maintenance plan we have different tasks available to us to help us optimize the performance of our databases like these:

- Shrinking a database
- Backing up a database
- Performing an operator notification
- Updating database statistics
- Verifying the integrity of a database
- Cleaning up leftover maintenance files
- Executing a SQL Server Agent job
- Executing a Transact-SQL statement
- Rebuilding an index
- Reorganizing an index
- Cleaning up database histories

My questions is what tasks should be performed on a 2 gb database in 1 day, 1 week and 1 month individually.

Comment: There are many factors to consider here.  Is your db for OLTP, OLAP, perhaps a hybrid?  How often and how long are your maintenance windows?  What's an acceptable amount of data loss?  (1 hour, 1 day, 1 week?)

Comment: [Why you should not shrink your data files](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/)